# Bootstrap and CSS

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, class, header

I got a Bootstrap template that was built by a company and I am doing a bunch of coding and additions to it but I am new to Bootstrap and I am having a problem. I added the vendor.css and theme.css files to my php header and I added the bootstrap.css file as well. My problem is when I try and use some of the bootstrap classes they dont work because of the vendor and theme css files being used. Some of them work but the appearance and functions are different. Is there any way around this so I can still use some of the bootstrap classes. I put the css files in the header in this order. theme, vendor, bootstrap and then my own css file at the bottom. Is the only way to do this by adding my own css file and make the changes. Any advice would be great. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand from your question that, some of your bootstrap classes are working and some of the them are not working.

In that case, I think it is bootstrap version issue. Obviously updated version class will not work in older version class.

Comment: I downloaded a template and am using it with bootstrap but they added their own css files called vendor and theme. I think is over riding the bootstrap original classes.